# Proof that the reduced density matrix of free fermions is thermal?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-information, fermions, many-body

I found [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27382/) here but it was partly unanswered. The question remains, namely:

Given a free theory of fermions in a bi-partite system $S=A\cup B$ with Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{ij} t_{ij}a^{\dagger}_ia_j\quad \longrightarrow \quad H = \sum_k E_k c^{\dagger}_kc_k
$$
**can anybody help me with proving that** given any eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ of $H$ with its associated density matrix $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ of $H$, the reduced density matrix $\rho_B=\text{tr}_A(\rho)$ has a "thermal" form:
$$
\rho_B \sim \exp(-H_B) \quad \text{with} \quad H_B=\sum_i h_{ij}c^{\dagger}_ic_j.
$$

---

The [proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0212631) I’m reading sketches that since $|\psi\rangle$ is a determinant (?), then its correlators factorise
$$
\langle c_i^{\dagger}c_j^{\dagger}c_kc_l\rangle_{\psi}= \langle c_n^{\dagger}c_l\rangle_{\psi} \langle c_m^{\dagger}c_k\rangle_{\psi} − \langle c^{\dagger}_nc_k \rangle_{\psi}\langle c^{\dagger}_mc_l\rangle _{\psi}
$$
($\langle \cdot \rangle_{\psi} := \langle \psi | \cdot | \psi \rangle$), therefore
$$
C_{ij} := \text{Tr}(\rho_B c_i^{\dagger} c_j)
$$
must factorise as well. According to Wick’s theorem, this property holds if (**why? is this if an *if and only if*?**) $\rho$ is the exponential of a free-fermion operator

$$
\rho_B = K\exp(-H_B) \quad \text{with} \quad H_B=\sum_i h_{ij}c^{\dagger}_ic_j.
$$
My problem is that this might not be the unique form of $\rho_B$. The above to me is a bit meaningless without the *if and only if*.

Comment: There is a discrepancy in notation between the first and the second equation. Also, the question seems to lack essential information about how the reduced density matrix is defined, what is its relation to $\psi$ etc. The question just doesn't make sense in its current form.

Comment: @Vadim The subscript $B$ indicates subsystem $B$, indeed those two equations are **not** describing the same thing. Given an eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ and its density matrix $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ the reduced density matrix $\rho_B$ in a say, bi-partite system $A\cup B$ is obtained by tracing out $A$: $\rho_B := \text{tr}_A(\rho)$. Does this make more sense?

Comment: I think you need to put all this in the question, since these are essential details. I still don't see though how a term *thermal* can be applied to a single state. By the way, what is the averaging  in your proof - the thermal averaging?

Comment: @Vadim Im adding this, thanks for the feedback! Well, once you trace over the degrees of freedom of $A$, the subsystem left (described by $\rho_B$) “looks” thermal, or that’s what they claim. It is not really surprising, one can view the rest of the system as a thermal bath to the degrees of freedom at $B$. I will also include that $\langle \cdot \rangle_{\psi}=\langle \psi | \cdot | \psi \rangle.$

Comment: The iff part of the argument is what really is dubious. The "if" works according to their reference [8] that proves the variant of the Wick theorem (that represents the products as sum of two-particle correlation functions and smaller product) to compute $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho abc\ldots)$ for the thermal state

Comment: Right, my problem is that this might not be the unique form of $\rho_B$. The above to me is a bit meaningless without the *iff*.

Comment: If you have Wick's theorem for arbitrary (many-operator) correlations, the "iff" follows trivially since the state is fully specified by all such correlations; if they can be determined from the two-point correlations then this must be the Gaussian state, since the Gaussian state satisfies Wick's theorem and, as stated, the state is determined uniquely by all correlations. Does this answer the unclear direction?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch so are you saying: *n-point correlators can be determined from 2-point correlators* $\implies \rho_B \sim \exp (-\sum_{ij} M_i^{\dagger} C_{ij} M_j)$ (with $dim(\rho_B)=dim(M_i)$). *But $\exp (-\sum_{ij} M_i^{\dagger} C_{ij} M_j)$ satisfies Wick’s theorem* $\implies \rho_B = \exp (-\sum_{ij} c_i^{\dagger} h_{ij} c_j)$ (with $c_i$ being the original fermionic operators)? I might need a little bit more help with this, I still dont see why this last form is unique.

Comment: I'm saying: (1) If I know all n-point correlators, for any n, this uniquely determined the state. Is that part ok? If yes, then (2) Gaussian states satisfy Wick's theorem. Is that part ok? Then, from (2): Gaussian states satisfy Wick's theorem, which fixes all n-point correlators, and from (1): A state where I know all n-point correlators is determined uniquely, so => it must be the Gaussian states (as it satisfies the desired properties, and such a state is unique).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I agree with (1) & (2). If I understood you correctly, your argument boils down to: if I find a form for $\rho_b$ that reproduces all the n-point correlators correctly then this is valid (I agree) and unique (?). I don't understand why one can't find another different form of $\rho_B$ such that it also reproduces the correct n-point functions.

Comment: Because a state ***is equivalent*** to all possible expectation values. States associate an expectation to every possible expectation value - nothing more, and nothing less. Thus, they are fully characterized by all possible expectation values. Anything else which is not specified by those would be entirely unphysical.

Comment: That's so true... I'm jealous of your knowledge! Thank you so much for your help and patience Norbert :)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I would offer you the bounty but I don't know how :(

Comment: Happy to help. I guess I'll have to write an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer assumes that you know that for Gaussian states, i.e. states of the form $\exp(-H_B)$, with $H_B$ quadratric in the fermionic operators, Wick's theorem holds, that is, $2n$-point correlators $\langle f_1\cdots f_{2n}\rangle$ can be expressed in terms of two-point correlators, where the $f_i$ are some fermionic operators (creation or annihiliation).

The question remains why this implies that a state which satisfies Wick's theorem must be a Gaussian state. The reason is that any quantum state is *entirely determined* by all its expectation values $\langle O\rangle$. For fermionic states, all admissible operators must have even parity, and thus, knowing all $\langle f_1\cdots f_{2n}\rangle$ means that you know all $\langle O\rangle$, and thus you know everything about the state: That is, the state is uniquely determined by all $\langle f_1\cdots f_{2n}\rangle$.

So if you have a state which satisfies Wick's theorem, you know it must be Gaussian, since there is a Gaussian state with the same $\langle f_1\cdots f_{2n}\rangle$, and those uniquely determine the state.

Comment: Great answer, it would be nice if you included the last comment you made on my question. Thank you so much for your help again!